# Documentation for ThreadWaitReason

Tags: winapi, mfc, wmi

I am searching the documentation for ThreadWaitReason 1..31. Especially I am interested for

```
ThreadWaitReason = 27 
ThreadWaitReason = 31
```

I have found is [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394494(v=vs.85).aspx but it's only listed until 1..20.

Comment: Did you _actually_ encounter the values 27 and 31 for the ThreadWaitReason field?

Comment: BTW: the documentation states that the ThreadWaitReason _value is only valid if the ThreadState member is set to Transition (6)_. Maybe this was not the case when you encountered 27 and 31.

Comment: Yes, I encounter the value 31 (sometimes 27). The ThreadState is 2. Maybe   I send too many PostMessages from a WorkerThread?

Comment: But if ThreadState is different from 6, the documentation says that ThreadWaitReason is meaningless. Quoting the documenation: _This value is only valid if the ThreadState member is set to Transition (6)._ So if ThreadState is not 6, the value in ThreadWaitReason is not valid (or in other words: it's meaningless)

Comment: @MichaelWalz - really here bug in documentation - `ThreadWaitReason` valid when thread state is `Waiting (5)`. about `Transition (6)` - i not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`KWAIT_REASON` enum is declared in `wdm.h` - you can view different values from it ( 27 is `WrResource` and 31 is `WrDispatchInt`).

the thread object (`KTHREAD`) itself have `WaitReason` field. and every time, before thread became wait (not active) system write to this field some reason value. when we, in kernel, direct call [`KeWaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553350(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`KeWaitForMultipleObjects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553324(v=vs.85).aspx) we by self set the *WaitReason* value. when we call another function, which can cause wait - system yourself set *WaitReason*. for example if call [`KeDelayExecutionThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551986(v=vs.85).aspx) (kernel mode implementation of `Sleep[Ex]` ) system set *WaitReason* to `WrDelayExecution`. when we call resource function ( [`ExAcquireResourceExclusiveLite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544351(v=vs.85).aspx) for example) - system [set](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ex/resource.c#L2619) *WaitReason* to `WrResource` (27) . when system swap thread, because it quantum expired - system [set](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ke/amd64/ctxswap.asm#L247) *WaitReason* to `WrDispatchInt` (31). and so on.

when we call `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemProcessInformation` - system [read](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/ex/sysinfo.c#L5186) value from *WaitReason* and return it in [`SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg750724.aspx) structure.

obviously the *WaitReason* have sense primary when thread is waiting - so it state is *Waiting (5)* . otherwise we got old value - reason why thread wait last time